How are Solana fees used to prioritise transactions?
Are Solana transactions prioritised based on the total priority fees included, the fees per reserved Compute Unit (SetComputeUnitLimit), or the fees per CU consumed?
In other words, which of these tx landing at the same time would get higher priority:
T1: SetComputeUnitLimit: 300_000 | SetComputeUnitPrice: 1000001 | CU consumed: 25_00
T2: SetComputeUnitLimit: 200_000 | SetComputeUnitPrice: 1000001 | CU consumed: 160_000


Prioritization isn't enforced by the protocol, but typically nodes will prefer to prioritize based on the compute unit price. For example, if my transaction has a compute unit price of 1_000_000, and takes 10 compute units, and your transaction has a compute unit price of 500_000, but takes 20 compute units, they will have the same total priority fee, but my transaction should be quicker to execute, which makes it more economically advantageous to the leader.
